# What is a good book to read about 3D printer settings?

Tags: print-quality

I've google searched many forums, blogs, and articles about 3D printer settings. There is a lot of guess work. Most of the materials are of amateur technical quality lacking the keen and systematic insight of an expert. Usually books are high in quality and written by experts.

I have built a 3D printer and would like to maximize my print quality. Are there any good books that have an in-dept analysis of printer settings?

Answer (score 3):

There may be books out there, but purchasing a book isn't in your best interest. The reason so much of the information seems to be from amateurs is because every 3d printer is different.

To find the correct settings for your printer you need to calibrate it based on the material, slicer software, hardware, and firmware. Your best option to find a good starting point is to check the manufacturer's website and look for a forum.

Even using the same printer and material as someone else has the potential to yield different results.